# Firebase sorting IDS

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I got the database in firebase where it is like [image]

There are 16 accounts in this example
I need to sort this firebase database on (AnID), because when I register a new account it goes on aplha order so the Ids will be sorted.

When I log the AnID's to the console this how its going...
I want it to be from 1-16 in order
[image]

Here is the code:

```
  const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
  const dbRefObject = dbRef.child('users');

  dbRefObject.on('child_added', snap => {
  var Uid = snap.val().userId;
  const testingRefToUidToGetChild = dbRefObject.child(Uid);
  testingRefToUidToGetChild.orderByChild("AnID").once('child_added', 
  function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
   });
  });
```

Comment: Unless you show the code that produces that output, there's not a lot we can say. Also: please don't share pictures of text, as it makes it impossible to search the text or to copy/paste your data/code in the answer to to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 
Am sorry I didn't know that... I fixed it I put the code in

Comment: I'm not really sure what the two nested listeners are meant to be doing. It also looks weird, since your second screenshot only shows the numbers, but in the code you're logging the entire snapshot. Instead of going back and forth, can you set up a small, minimal jsbin that reproduces the problem? You might want to read on how to create such an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and why it is useful.